# TypeError at /gym/ninja/ninja() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, typeerror

actually i am trying to sumbit the details from my contact from to them  of my django app but i am facing same error with all the
varriable i am am able to get the details from my html page and can
print it in my vs code cmd but when i try to save it in my model i
face same error for all variable so please can anyone help me with it

html code:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="container">
         <div class="form-row">
             <div class="col">
                 <label for="inputEmail1">E-mail</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emails" id="emails" placeholder="Enter your E-mail">
             </div>
             <div class="col">
                 <label for="inputEmail2">Phone-Number</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phones" id="phones" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-row">
             <div class="col">
                 <label for="inputEmail1">Age</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ages" id="ages" placeholder="Enter your age">
             </div>
             <div class="col">
                 <label for="inputEmail2">Height</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="height" id="height" placeholder="Enter your height">
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-row">
             <div class="col">
                 <label for="inputEmail4">Weight</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="weight" id="weight" placeholder="Enter your weight">
             </div>
             <div class="col">
                 <label for="inputEmail3">Food Habit</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="habit" id="habit" placeholder="Are you veg/non-veg/vegan">
             </div>
         </div>
         <br>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Enter other important detail\'s</label>
             <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your message here....."
              id="messagess"
              name="messagess"
              rows="5"></textarea>
         </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
     </div>     
</form>
```

my model that i have used:

```
 class ninja(models.Model):
     ninjaemail= models.CharField(max_length=50)
     phones = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     ages = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     height = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     weight = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     habit = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     message = models.CharField(max_length=800)
```

my views.py where i am facing issue

```
def ninja(request):
     if request.method=='POST':
          emails = request.POST['emails']
          phones = request.POST['phones']
          ages = request.POST['ages']
          height = request.POST['height']
          weight = request.POST['weight']
          habit = request.POST['habit']
          messagess = request.POST['messagess']
          ninj=ninja(ninjaemail=emails,phones=phones,ages=ages,height=height,weight=weight,habit=habit,messages=messagess)
         ninj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ninja model has a property `message` but when you create your ninja instance you try to set the property `messagess`.

So change the line

```
ninj=ninja(ninjaemail=emails,phones=phones,ages=ages,height=height,weight=weight,habit=habit,messagess=messagess)
```

to

```
ninj = ninja(ninjaemail=emails,
           phones=phones,
           ages=ages,
           height=height,
           weight=weight,
           habit=habit,
           message=messagess
     )
```

That the Error also occures for every other variable could be caused by your naming. You try to create a ninja object by calling `ninja(ninjaemail= ....)` inside a `ninja` method. So it probably doesn't call the Object but the method.
Change your naming like this:

```
class ninja(models.Model):
     ...
```

to

```
class Ninja(models.Model):
    ...
```

and

```
def ninja(request):
    ...
```

to

```
def create_ninja(request):
   ...
```

Comment: i did tha change but  i am still facing the isseue with every varibale

Comment: ok wait. via calling ninja(ninjaemail=emails, ...) your not actually creating an instance of the object type ninja your calling the def ninja (recursively). You should change your naming: name the model `Ninja` not `ninja` and name the function `create_ninja` not `ninja`. I updated my answer

Comment: i updated my code the way u told still facing same error